# Load html file into html file in node

Tags: html, node.js, load

I want to load a header.html into index.html
i try this two:
 1. `<link rel="import" href="html/header.html">`
 2. `<script src="html/header.html"></script>`

I can see a load header.html suing console.log
 1 is no log but, didn't show the result
 2 had a log like this: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' header.html`

So, I still try like 2 version
suddenly  I ask a few something myself.

If I load the haeder.html
How to parse data between to HTML files?
* import CSS and HTML data in header.html
* import header.html at head tag and html data

How to work the situation above?

- want to write the code but, that's so long
  instead URL :
  https://github.com/macfa/ndoejs.git
- etc
  I trying to explain this situation using translate
  hope to understand the context above.

Answer (score 0):

Including HTML is done by using a w3-include-html attribute:

```
 <div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
```

More info : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but, I can't understand : (
if you're ok I want some examples...
To question I have is how to separate files and how to load an HTML file
and merge a loaded file into another HTML file
LIKE <?php include 'header.php' ?>